# modify Magento's default Account dashboard

Tags: magento

i tried editing the phtml files (dashboard.phtml) under

template > customer > account

but the account dashboard stays the same. what am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which theme were you editing?  There are numerous installed by default, and the one which is displayed is set in System>Config>Design.  If you're editing `app/design/frontend/base/default/template`, then make sure you don't have any entry in the Design.

Also, make sure you disable the cache in System>Cache Management while doing your development, but turn it on in production!

JD

Comment: i'm editing a custom (commercial) theme. would the DEFAULT theme override the custom layout files?

Comment: if i edit the dashboard.phtml under DEFAULT, will it override the dashboard.phtml under MYTHEME?

Comment: If the commercial theme has a template in `template/customer/account/`, then that will override the `base/default/template/customer/account`

Answer (score 0):

You should go to **app/design/frontend/base/default/template**, and then look up for the xml file you dont want to show in the personal account dashboard. For instance: to remove "my downloadble products" from the dashboard, you should edit **downloadable.xml**, and look for this code:

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>
    </reference>
```

Then, do

```
<!--<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>-->
```

This way you will remove the "my downloadble products" link from the dashboard.

Hope that it helps